# Why F- is more stable than CH3-

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

When I was reading Organic textbook, I saw a statement of 'F- is more stable than CH3- because the F has a greater electronegativity'. I agree with the explanation 'because of its high electronegativity, F can hold the electrons very well'. But I am just confused about: as the F has great electronegativity, it can react with other cations/electrophile very easily, making it reactive thus unstable. So I am just very confused about this contradiction.

Comment: True, F has great electronegativity and hence is very reactive, but _what happens when it reacts_  with something? Does it still remain the same?

Comment: High electronegativity does not imply high nucleophilicity or high basicity, but it is a bit difficult to grasp these concepts.

Comment: CH3-  as typified by methyl lithium is an exteremely strong base and will tear protons off most things except other alkanes.